# Using pandas to csv, how to organize time and numerical data in a multi-level index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by, resampling

Using pandas to write to a csv, I want Monthly Income sums for each unique Source. Month is in datetime format.

I have tried resampling and groupby methods, but groupby neglects month and resampling neglects source. I currently have a multi-level index with Month and Source as indexes.

```
   Month        Source   Income
2019-03-01        A        100
2019-03-05        B        50
2019-03-06        A        4
2019-03-22        C        60
2019-04-23        A        40
2019-04-24        A        100
2019-04-24        C        30
2019-06-1         C        100
2019-06-1         B        90
2019-06-8         B        20
2019-06-12        A        50
2019-06-27        C        50
```

I can groupby Source which neglects date, or I can resample for date which neglects source. I want monthly sums for each unique source.

Comment: You want `df.groupby(['Source', 'Month']).sum().reset_index()`?

Comment: `df.groupby([df['Source'], df['Month'].dt.month]).sum()` while they month and source are not indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have in the *Month* column is a *Timestamp*. So you can separate the month attribute of this *Timestamp* and afterward apply the *groupby* method, like this:

```
df.columns = ['Timestamp', 'Source', 'Income']

month_list = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    month_list.append(df.loc[i,'Timestamp'].month)

df['Month'] = month_list

df1 = df.groupby(['Month', 'Source']).sum()
```

The output should be like this:

```
               Income
Month   Source  
3          A    104
           B    50
           C    60
4          A    140
           C    30
6          A    50
           B    110
           C    150
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I had some messed up indexing going on, but once I fixed that using df = df.reset_index(drop=True)      this worked perfectly. Thanks